# creating sqlite3 database has different results on ipad 2 and ipad mini 2

Tags: ios, ipad, sqlite

When I ran the following codes on the devices, I got different results.

```
sqlite3 *db;
if (sqlite3_open([sourceFile UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char* key = [passWord UTF8String];
    sqlite3_key(db, key, (int)strlen(key));

    ........

}
```

It worked successfully on ipad 2(ios 9.3.5), but failed on ipad mini 2(ios 9.3.5). Why?

The code {sqlite3_open([sourceFile UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK} on ipad 2 and ipad mini 2 is all true.
The code {sqlite3_key(db, key, (int)strlen(key))} on ipad 2 work successfully, but on ipad mini 2 fail.

What's the difference between the two devices?

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Different SQLite library, different key, different database, …

Comment: Today,I also test on ipad air 2, it works successfully.
Why only ipad mini 2 crash?
Is there anything different between ipad mini 2 and other ipads?